# Bug free version of string substitution

Tags: python, string, algorithm, substitution

I am trapped in a quite straight forward problem, but after some tweak, I simply cannot find an easy and efficient algorithm to do this.

So basically I have a string, which contains certain elements, for instance:

```
l = "test %1, %13, %14, %15"
```

And a map:

```
dict = {"%1": "%33", "%13": "%14", "%14", "%15", "%15": "%17"}
```

And I would like to do the following stuff:

```
for k in dict.keys():
    l = l.replace(k, dict[k])
```

So what I am expecting is:

```
l = "test %33, %14, %15, %17"
```

But apparently this is not feasible, since there are some conflict between keys and values. So the above code would output:

```
l = "test %33, %17, %17, %17"
```

Sorry for such native problem, but how should I solve this and get my expected output? Note that the length of each key/value is not fixed, so I cannot do something like:

```
m_idx = l_copy.find(key)
l = l[:m_idx] + dict[key] + l[m_idx+len(key):]
```

Because the length is not fixed, the above code is still buggy.

Am I clear on this? Any suggestion would be appreciated very much!

======= update

So all keys follow this pattern of %[0-9]+.

Comment: `dict = {"%1": "%33", "%13": "%14", "%14", "%15", "%15": "%17"}` do you mean: `dict = {"%1": "%33", "%13": "%14", "%14": "%15", "%15": "%17"}`

Comment: Do all keys follow this pattern of %[0-9]+?

Comment: Your problem is not well-constrained, for example, %13 in input matches both %13 and %1 in the translation table. Before the question is answerable, you'll need to provide extra clarification here about a) what is to be considered a boundary, and/or b) specify an order of priority when multiple overlapping replacements are possible.

Comment: @coldspeed Yes! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a `lambda`:

```
import re
l = "test %1, %13, %14, %15"
_dict = {"%1": "%33", "%13": "%14", "%14":"%15", "%15": "%17"}
new_l = re.sub('%\d+', lambda x:_dict[x.group()], l)
```

Output:

```
'test %33, %14, %15, %17'
```

You can use `dict.get` to prevent a `KeyError` by providing a default value should the key not be present in `_dict`:

```
new_l = re.sub('%\d+', lambda x:_dict.get(x.group(), x.group()), l)
```

Comment: `new_l = re.sub('%\d+', lambda x:_dict.get(x.group(),x.group()), l)` to avoid keyerrors? I dont get the dv ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner Possibly, will add `dict.get` solution.

Comment: It assumes all keys are of the form `%\d+`, and that the greediest match is the correct match. That *might* be a good assumption, but needs to be clarified in the question and/or the answer.

Comment: @wim The OP has just posted a clarification.

Comment: OK, but now that it has been clarified - it's a dupe.

Comment: Thank you @Ajax1234 . This is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @lllllllllllll Glad to help!